# Simplification of CFG

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Recently i was studying removal of useless symbols in productions given in Ullman Hopcroft.

The grammar goes as follows

S-> aAa | aBC

A -> aS | bD

B - > aBa | b

C-> abb | DD

D -> aDa

In the explanation that follows, we eliminate D obviously, but the removal of C still baffles me. As D is non generating, but C is both generating and reachable. So why delete C?

The resultant grammar is shown as

S->aAa

A->aS

B->aBa | b

Here is the link to the photo of the page in the book just in case

Page 240:

[image]

Page 241:

[image]

Comment: Apparently Hopcroft and Ullman were wrong. There is no reason to eliminate $C$.

Comment: I though so too, so I mailed Ullman saying if this is incorrect; he replied that there is a simple explanation to this; but he wont say it because he talks only to bonafide instructors about the book and that he cannot tutor the whole world :/

Comment: By the way, in the resulting grammar $B$ is unreachable so can be removed. Perhaps Ullman was joking with you. He's right not to answer everyone, the book is quite popular.

Comment: The presence of B is justified in the text as;    "Since S has a production with right-hand sides aAa and aBC, we conclude that A,B,C and a are reachable. B has production B->b. We therefore conclude b is reachable. Now no more symbols can be added to the reachable set, which is {S, A, B, a, b}." In which...again C is magically ignored...if he is joking; it's a bad joke man..especially for a student who is learning from his book

Comment: The grammars are not equivalent since the first produces at least the word $ababb$ while the second doesn't produce anything. Are you sure you copied the result correctly?

Comment: What edition and page is this? I could only find the 2001 edition (I think that's the second) and on pages 256 and following, the example grammar is different.

Comment: Yes, I am sure...I checked it multiple times as I too was confused. We cant upload pictures can we? Or else I would have.

Comment: This is the third edition meant for the Indian Subcontinent, it is on page 240 of that book

Comment: You can upload pictures, unless that's reputation-dependent; even then you can upload to some image hosting service and include a link.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/17wcw4/8

Comment: Could you post page 241 as well? As it is, that looks wrong.

Comment: Page 241 is in the question Page 243 (where the C was ignored in the final reachable set)

http://tinypic.com/r/2h6u5qt/8

Comment: Find a similar error in The Art of Computer Programming, and you are a rich man. (well, somewhat richer).

Comment: It is odd that Ullman would answer that this is not a mistake, because it clearly is. There are errata for that book, so I would expect that he answers with "yeah that's wrong, thanks for pointing it out" if it is a mistake.

Comment: You may have received a standard letter from secretarial help. The point to check, before writing, is to make sure it still is in the latest printing of the book. If not, there is no point in writing, They cannot change the past, only the future, for its foreseeable self

Answer (score 1):

C isn't Part of the grammar recursion. As it expands to Terminals only, it is artificial in the Sense That it is only used for notational convenience while it is unnecessary for expressing the CFG.

The simplified grammar obviously contains a typo, as no words containing `b` are derivable contradicting `S -> aBC -> abC -> ababb` which the original grammar allows.

The first rule should probably read `S -> aAa | aBabb`.

Comment: Finding a *minimal* grammar is a completely different task than finding a *reduced* grammar. In particuar, iirc, the former is not computable while there are efficient algorithms for the latter. (I assume that reduced grammars are the topic here.)

Comment: In particular, reducing the grammar does not change the parse trees, while removing C in this case does change them.